# Clean in forms doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make my user's username `lowercase`. But somehow it doesn't work. I just can't see a mistake... Why is it not working?

Model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField()

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
        return username
```

Comment: are you sure this points to the `User` model, and not `UserProfile` ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that uses the forms, e.g. the views.

Comment: Why have you shown the code for UserProfile? This appears to have nothing whatsoever to do with the form, which is based on User instead and does not use any fields from UserProfile.